# Solving a Markov Matrix for steady state probabilities.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

Let $P$ denote the transition matrix and $\pi$ be the vector ($1 \times 8$)of steady-state probabilities. $\pi_1$ is the proportion of time spent in state $1$.

I have $P$, an $8\times 8$ matrix, hence I need to solve $\pi P=\pi$ Additional condition is that $\sum \pi_i =1$

Rearranging $\pi P-\pi=0$ or $\pi(P-I)=(0,...,0)$.

Now $\pi = 0\times (P-I)^{-1}=0$ which is not true.

I don't really want to solve all 8 equations, because that is a lot of hassle. I'm trying to use MATLAB to give me an easy solution.

Comment: $P-I$ is always singular - that's the very reason a steady state exists.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus thanks, so the only way to solve it is to use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: If you can easily invert matrices with MATLAB, you can try to remove the $ith$ column of P and replace it by $(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)^T$ and then try to invert. If it's invertible (it may or may not work for several i, it's not obvious which ones), then multiply the ith standard unit vector by it. The result should be $\pi$ i think.